# Which sentence is more common?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which way do you prefer to say this sentence: "inaccurate pruning makes the trees out of shape" or "inaccurate pruning puts the trees into deformed shape"?

Comment: Can I choose 'Careless pruning will leave you with a badly deformed tree'?

Comment: Google Books claims 617 instances of ["incorrect pruning"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22incorrect+pruning%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but only 2 of ["inaccurate pruning"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inaccurate+pruning%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (and one of those is about pruning *algorithms*, not trees). Since this is basically a *proofreading* question, that's probably the most "unidiomatic" aspect of OP's texts

Comment: That's right! "incorrect pruning" is more idiomatic, although terms such as "inaccurate pruning" or "substandard pruning" are also used as technical collocations in agricultural science.

Comment: I would hazard the guess that both sentences are equally common. Each having been produced exactly once — by yourself, on this page. As a side note, a more descriptive title would be nice. You will get far more views. People just don't click on vague links. Describe the actual problem, not its type.

Answer (score 1):

Neither seem particularly idiomatic to me.

I'd go for either *"Inaccurate pruning deforms trees"* or *"Inaccurate pruning can deform trees"* depending on the inevitability, or otherwise, of the consequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are wrong. The former does not allude to the reality of the situation, that is, the trees are not really *made* to be out of shape but they *grow* to be out of shape.

Similarly, pruning doesn't really 'put' anything.

Therefore, I would say the correct sentence is:

**"Inaccurate pruning makes the trees grow out of shape."**

Or, even better:

**"Inaccurate pruning causes the trees to grow out of shape."**